# How to get the Apple Watch hardware identifier?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

This page http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models seems to suggest that the identifiers for the new apple watches are "Watch 1,1" and "Watch 1,2"

Does anyone know how to get this identifier in code for a connected watch? 
`[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice]` seems to only give me the screen bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no WatchKit method to obtain the hardware identifier. To distinguish between the 38mm and 42mm Watches, an Apple employee in the dev forums recommended using the `screenBounds` property on `WKInterfaceDevice`. Something like this:

```
if ([WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice].screenBounds.size.width == 136.0f) {
    // 38mm
}
else {
    // 42mm
}
```