# Persistent storage on Apple watch

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I am looking for a way to store something on the Apple watch app that I can read later on enabling me to identify it uniquely.

I don't see any API at the moment that would let me do this. The closest I have got is to save an image in cache but since its just a cache, its not reliable.

My goal is to uniquely identify an Apple Watch.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand `enabling me to identify it uniquely`, there is nothing that you can identify any app in iOS, but in WatchKit scenario you have `group`, using which you can share data between apps and watch kit app.

Comment: @iphonic Imagine something on the lines of UUID but for the watch

Comment: Oh ok, But I don't think this is going to happen as Apple Watch seems to always paired with the iPhone, and any third Party app would need iPhone App, which can actually deal with UUIDs. But not in case of Apple Watch.

Comment: A watch needs a phone to run to app - True. but that doesn't restrict me from bringing another watch, pair it to the phone and start using the app. You see where I'm getting with this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can save information to be accessible from both watch and iPhone in NSUserDefaults and App Groups like this:

`let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.your-bundle-id.app-group-name")`

where `"group.com.your-bundle-id.app-group-name"` is your app group identifier.

For more details about NSUserDefaults and other ways to share data between Watch and iPhone see 
[Architecting Your App 
for the Apple Watch](https://realm.io/news/architecting-app-apple-watch-natashatherobot/)

Comment: User defaults can share the data but it wont help in identifying the watch uniquely.

Comment: Maybe storing `[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]` in user defaults and have your own uuid for particular watch is that what you need.

Comment: the second part of your answer "have your own uuid for particular watch" is exactly what I am looking for.. How do I get a unique uuid for a corresponding watch.

Comment: I dont think you can do that with existent WatchKit API. You can generate UUID and store it somewhere, maybe somehow in image cache: _When your app’s caches fill up, you must remove existing images from the cache before attempting to add new ones._ ([Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/Images.html)).

Comment: If you see my question, I have already mentioned using image cache for this. However, the cache (as its name suggests) cannot guarantee that this image will be present forever and you might not even know when OS clears up your cache when it needs. Hence the question title (persistent storage on Apple watch)

Answer (score 1):

User App Groups OR NSUserDefaults to share data between your iOS apps.

> Easily share small amounts of data between your iOS app and your
>   WatchKit extension with App Groups and NSUserDefaults. For access to
>   other resources, such as a Core Data store, use a shared container
>   between your iOS app and your WatchKit extension to simplify data
>   access and provide up to date information.

Comment: data sharing is not the issue here. It's the physical watch identification (probably with some kind of identifier) that I need

Comment: I think so.. Haven't found an alternative yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this would be very useful, not only for identifying the watch, but also to load the UI faster (without synchronizing lots of data via Bluetooth first).

However, there seems to be no solution at the moment to do this.

It also seems to be impossible to get the [hardware identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856632/how-to-get-the-apple-watch-hardware-identifier) of the watch.

Maybe this will be possible once normal third-party developers are allowed to write real watch apps (not just extensions of iPhone apps). The WWDC is in June.

Comment: user defaults wont solve the purpose since I want to identify the watch uniquely and the userdefaults will reside in the phone. Thanks for your comment though.

Comment: Very good question! It seems that it is also not possible to get the hardware identifier of the watch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856632/how-to-get-the-apple-watch-hardware-identifier. Maybe there will be a solution soon (WWDC). :)

Comment: yep hopefully. Fingers crossed ! :)